# How to enable PCI bridge for WOL?

Tags: 12.04, wakeonlan

In order to make sure that the PCI bridge is ready for WOL, I tried placing

```
sudo sh -c 'echo enabled > /sys/class/pci_bus/0000:00/device/0000:00:1c.0/power/wakeup'
```

in `/etc/rc.local`

Apparently, this file does not exist (yet?) at the time `rc.local` is called, because I got an error that the folder could not be found. If I copy/paste the instruction in the terminal window, the system returns no error.

I assume this is some sort of timing issue, does anybody know how to do this correctly ?

or if somebody can show me a reference where to find more info on how the folder structure is built for `/sys/class`, that might help too !

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:  http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/220-ubuntu-resume-usb-hid

Though, it's only intended for USB devices, the same thing applies for pci devices.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to use `sysfsutils` rather than `/etc/rc.local`. Check you have the prerequisite package:

```
sudo apt-get install sysfsutils
```

now edit the file `/etc/sysfs.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/sysfs.conf
```

at the end of the file add

```
class/pci_bus/0000:00/device/0000:00:1c.0/power/wakeup = enabled
```

Save and exit.

On reboot you will find:

```
$ cat /sys/class/pci_bus/0000:00/device/0000:00:1c.0/power/wakeup
enabled
```

`sysfs` mounted on `/sys` isn't a real filesystem - it's a userspace window into the kernel with a few configurable access points like this one - they aren't real files.